# Got runtime error, when inserting list item <li> in to a paragraph <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web

Look at the following code for example:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication18._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="someId"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML = "<ul><li>Some content</li></ul>";
    </script>
</body>
```

In the Visual Studio 2013, debug mode, I got a runtime error. I have noticed that the p tag doesn't allow any block-level tags within it according W3C rules.

But if I created a static html file, it runs fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <p id="someId"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML = "<ul><li>Some content</li></ul>";
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I wonder why there is a runtime error when running with Visual studio, but it’s ok with a static file? Thanks.
I am using visual studio 2013, and IE 11.

Comment: Could be a coincidence that something else that exists only in that aspx is causing the runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Html in general is more forgiving. Semantically however it's not correct. So VS complains about it because you don't follow the rules.

Usually somewhere in `Tools` > `Options` >

- `Text Editor` >

  - `HTML` > `Advanced`
  - `HTML (Web Forms)` > `Validation`
  - `JavaScript` > `Intellisense` (?)

Any indication in the error pane?